# Due diligence preventing leaks between condos

Tags: plumbing

I wish to expand the size of my bathroom in my condo and will require the approval of my condo association.  Currently, all bathrooms in the building are stacked vertically - so if a leak occurs it will leak into another bathroom.  If I take a portion of the adjoining closet then any future leak could occur into the dry closet below.

Besides installing a floor drain and correctly pitching the floor. Are there techniques that can be used to direct a future leak towards the existing bathroom area?

Are there secondary barriers that can installed in between the units to direct leaks?

What due diligence can I present to the Condo Association to show I am doing everything possible to minimize any impact of future leaks?

Comment: I don't know if it will appease your condo association, but there's no guarantee that a leak will appear in the room directly below anyway. Water can run along beams, pipes, etc. and show up almost anywhere. The bathrooms were almost certainly built on top of each other to ease construction, not for leak control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how technical your board members are but I think an easy thing to do is waterproof the entire bathroom.  I feel like I am giving you some Holmes advice (totally overdoing something) but you can lay a Kerdi membrane over the entire floor and up 4-6 inches on the wall and of course your whole shower area.  You could virtually take a bath in your entire bathroom if this was installed correctly without a leak.

Now as Henry pointed out the plumbing can leak almost anywhere.  So maybe they want all of the plumbing along a wall or two.  If these are the things they want (I wouldn't bring it up) then you could configure your layout plus the waterproofing to hopefully meet their standards.  If your association is like most then it is probably more of how you get along with everyone vs. what you are looking to do.